# Enable Service Broker when deploying solution

Tags: sql-server, service-broker, ssdt, deployment

I'm having an issue deploying the latest build of a database solution after creating some service broker objects. I am thinking that it could be related to not having service broker enabled on the database, as it gets created as part of the build, then deployed straight away.

Where can I set the "ENABLE BROKER" option so it get's executed before deploy, but after the database is created by SQLPackage ?

Comment: Do you have the `EnableBroker` database option set in your database project? I would expect SqlPackage to honor it during deployment.

Comment: @DanGuzman I couldn't find the option - I'll have a look again - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the latest SSDT version, the EnableBroker option is under Database Settings-->Miscellaneous-->Service broker options.  I would expect SqlPackage to honor this specification.

Comment: Database settings is present in project properties -> Project options